# SimpleXMLElement set value to special characters

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to send special characters (less than, greater than) to the text of a node using SimpleXMLElement, but it's converting it to the escaped values.

```
$header[0] = "%SET(Amt_,<AMT>". $amt . "</AMT>) \n" .$header[0];
```

The above results in the following in the XML file:

```
 %SET(Amt_,&lt;AMT&gt;100&lt;/AMT&gt;)
```

I tried using html_entity_decode and it still wrote to file the same way. Is there any way to write 'special' characters to the text value of a simplexmlelement object?

**clarification:** I want to write the actual characters '<' and '>' to the file when `$header->asXML()` is called. Currently the escaped versions are what is written to file.

Comment: are seeing the file on a browser or directly ?

Comment: XML containing unescaped special characters is not valid and will throw an error.

Comment: It displays correctly on a browser, but I'm concerned with the actual contents of the file -- it is being used as input to another program, which will not interpret &gt; or &lt; as < or >

Answer (score 1):

Use `htmlspecialchars` while sending data and `htmlspecialchars_decode` whenever you want to get the original string.

```
<?php
  $amt = 100;
  $header[0] = "Some Value";
  $header[0] = "%SET(Amt_,<AMT>". $amt . "</AMT>) \n" .$header[0];
  $node =  htmlspecialchars($header[0]); 
  $value = htmlspecialchars_decode($node);
  file_put_contents("filename.txt", $value);
  echo "written on file";
?>
```

Comment: This still doesn't write the <,> to file.


`%SET(Amt_,&amp;lt;AMT&amp;gt;100&amp;lt;/AMT&amp;gt;)`

Answer (score 0):

A work around that works for my case, I reopened the file contents, decoded it and resaved it to file.

```
$xml->asXML('test.xml');
$coded = file_get_contents('test.xml');
file_put_contents('test.xml', htmlspecialchars_decode($coded), LOCK_EX);
```